# Any way to make Project References work without loading them in the solution in Expression Blend?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, reference, resourcedictionary, blend-2012

We have a Solution with 25 projects in it referencing each other and it builds successfully in  Visual Studio 2012.

But when it comes to Expression Blend (Blend for Visual Studio 2012), I am having the following issues :

1) The solution fails to build. Gives me missing references, missing resource dictionary errors.
2) Takes long time to load or perform any operation.

I am wondering if there is any way to just load my main project in to a solution and still make the project references work.

Does the order in which the individual projects are compiled in a solution matter in Expression Blend? I am not sure why the blend is unable to find the resource dictionaries when it is seen clearly in Visual Studio 2012.